# Malformed CSV file and Pandas read_csv by chunk

Tags: python, csv, pandas

i got a csv file: 22 Go size,  46000000 lines
to save memory, csvfile is read and processed by chunk.

```
tp = pd.read_csv(f_in, sep=',', chunksize=1000, encoding='utf-8',quotechar='"') 
for chunk in tp: 
   chunk;
```

but the file is malformed and raise an exception :

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 87 fields in line 15092657, saw 162
```

is there a way to trash this chunk and continue the loop with next chunk ?

Comment: Does it skip if you try this: `tp = pd.read_csv(f_in, sep=',', engine='c', chunksize=1000, encoding='utf-8',quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)?`

Comment: will give a try, and get back to you with results.

Answer (score 1):

The question is similar to an earlier asked one found here:
[Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

As it says in the answers you have to be aware that using error_bad_lines=False removes the line and suggests a better way is to investigate the line in your dataset.

Comment: The OP is asking to skip the chunk, not specifically to investigate why the line fails

Answer (score 1):

As EdChum says, question was how to skip the chunk, and adding  'error_bad_lines=False' do the trick.
Is there a way to intercept the trace giving bad lines  and count faulty line ?

Comment: From the docs: `warn_bad_lines : boolean, default True
If error_bad_lines is False, and warn_bad_lines is True, a warning for each “bad line” will be output. (Only valid with C parser).` so if you turn `error_bad_lines=False` then it should output a warning which should contain the line number, you then have to inspect each of these warnings

Answer (score 1):

To intercept the bad line, i use the following code:

```
# somewhere to store output
err = StringIO.StringIO()
# save a reference to real stderr so we can restore later
oldstderr = sys.stderr
# set stderr to our StringIO instance
sys.stderr = err

tp = pd.read_csv(f_in, sep=',', chunksize=1000, encoding='utf-8',quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False) 
for chunk in tp:
      chunk

# restore stderr 
sys.stderr = oldstderr

# print(or use) the stored value from previous print
print err.len + 'lines skipped.'
print err.getvalue()
err.close()
```