# UnicodeDecodeError when reading CSV File into Dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using the code below to read a csv file into a dataframe. However, I get the error `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2` and hence I changed `pd.read_csv('D:/TRYOUT.csv')` to `pd.read_csv('D:/TRYOUT.csv', error_bad_lines=False)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data). However, I now get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte` in the same line.

```
def ExcelFileReader():
    mergedf = pd.read_csv('D:/TRYOUT.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
    return mergedf
```

Comment: Could you supply an example CSV file which causes a failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, you probably need to use `pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin-1')`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and had to use

```
utf-8-sig
```

as the encoding,

The reason i used utf-8-sig is because if you do ever get non-Latin characters it wont be able to deal with it correctly. There are a few ways of getting around the problem, but i guess you can just choose the best that suits your needs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to exclude the rows providing error and ignore the malformed data then you need to use:

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding="utf8", error_bad_lines=False, encoding_errors="ignore")
```