# Error while reading Boston data from UCL website using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

Any  help please for reading this file from url website.

```
eurl = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data'
data = pandas.read_csv(url, sep=',', header = None)
```

I tried sep=',', sep=';' and sep='\t' but the data read like this
[image]

but with

```
data = pandas.read_csv(url, sep=' ', header = None)
```

I received an error,

```
 pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)()
 pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)()
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:8970)()
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8838)()
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:22649)()
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 30 fields in line 2, saw 31
```

Maybe same question asked here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) but the accepted answer does not help me.

any help please to read this file from the url provide it.

BTW, I know there is Boston = load_boston() to read this data but when I read it from this function, the attribute 'MEDV' in the dataset does not download with the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple spaces used as a delimiter, that's why it's not working when you use a single space as a delimiter (`sep=' '`)

you can do it using `sep='\s+'`:

```
In [171]: data = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', header = None)

In [172]: data.shape
Out[172]: (506, 14)

In [173]: data.head()
Out[173]:
        0     1     2   3      4      5     6       7   8      9     10      11    12    13
0  0.00632  18.0  2.31   0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900   1  296.0  15.3  396.90  4.98  24.0
1  0.02731   0.0  7.07   0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671   2  242.0  17.8  396.90  9.14  21.6
2  0.02729   0.0  7.07   0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671   2  242.0  17.8  392.83  4.03  34.7
3  0.03237   0.0  2.18   0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622   3  222.0  18.7  394.63  2.94  33.4
4  0.06905   0.0  2.18   0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622   3  222.0  18.7  396.90  5.33  36.2
```

or using `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
In [174]: data = pd.read_csv(url, delim_whitespace=True, header = None)

In [175]: data.shape
Out[175]: (506, 14)

In [176]: data.head()
Out[176]:
        0     1     2   3      4      5     6       7   8      9     10      11    12    13
0  0.00632  18.0  2.31   0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900   1  296.0  15.3  396.90  4.98  24.0
1  0.02731   0.0  7.07   0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671   2  242.0  17.8  396.90  9.14  21.6
2  0.02729   0.0  7.07   0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671   2  242.0  17.8  392.83  4.03  34.7
3  0.03237   0.0  2.18   0  0.458  6.998  45.8  6.0622   3  222.0  18.7  394.63  2.94  33.4
4  0.06905   0.0  2.18   0  0.458  7.147  54.2  6.0622   3  222.0  18.7  396.90  5.33  36.2
```