# pandas.read_csv with error_bad_lines=False seems to duplicates rows

Tags: python, pandas

While importing a csv with

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\t')
```

I encountered error 
*Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 173840, saw 3*

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) I applied

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Instead of just skipping the problematic row, it seems that it started copying again from a random line (89465 in this case).

Actual data in the original csv:

[image: actual data]

Data copied from the csv:

[image: weird error]

Do you have any idea about why is this happening and what could I do to prevent it?

Comment: Simple check: what is the size of the df and of the file?

Comment: You can also try to switch from the C to the Python engine, [`pd.read_csv('file.csv',engine='python')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: you can directly use `pd.read_table()` for tab separated files.

Comment: @Roelant the file has 2617762 rows and occupies 34MB, but I had no problem at all with a similar file 9 times bigger.

Comment: @KaranChudasama thanks, that worked fine :) But most of all I was curious about the bizarre result.