# Read csv online with error Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, parsing

The datafile in the format of .csv can successfully readed in the local computer.

```
df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
```

[image]

The file is upload [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ew62yi0v07tjub/data-1.csv?dl=0).

However, I use two method with the uploading data in Dropbox or Github, the reading process all occured error as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ew62yi0v07tjub/data-1.csv?dl=0")
```

> error: 
>     pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10364)()
>     pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10640)()
>   pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11386)()
>   pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11257)()
>   pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:26979)()
>   CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/envhyf/Notebook/blob/master/data-1.csv")
```

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 116, saw 3

Thus, my question is why the  csv file can be read in my own computer, but failed in the  cloud?

How to fix this problem. I have tried the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) by adding `error_bad_lines=False`. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For github you can use `raw` data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/envhyf/Notebook/master/data-1.csv")
```

And for `dropbox` need `dl=1`, info from [this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download):

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcn75c65222dtfk/data-1.csv?dl=1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried and successfully read my datafile.

Comment: Thus, I suspected that the original url (e.g., https://github.com/xxx) is not supported for directly reading for pandas?

Comment: OK. Thanks for your carefully comments.

Comment: oops, I get solution for dropbox too. So added to answer and deleted comments

Comment: why the `dl` should set to be 1?

Comment: If it is `0` it return html page, see this - https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Comment: Thanks! I understand.