# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I run this command:

```
k1=pd.read_table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/chipotle.tsv")
```

I  receive this error:

Command on Pandas: attached.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 pd.read_table('')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
>   index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
>   converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
>   encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
>   skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray,
>   compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       654 
>   --> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       656 
>       657     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       409 
>       410     try:
>   --> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
>       412     finally:
>       413         parser.close()
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in read(self, nrows)    1003                 raise
>   ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')    1004 
>   -> 1005         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)    1006     1007         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in read(self, nrows)    1746     def read(self, nrows=None):    1747
>   try:
>   -> 1748             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1749         except StopIteration:    1750             if self._first_chunk:
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
>   (pandas_libs\parsers.c:10862)()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
>   (pandas_libs\parsers.c:11138)()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
>   (pandas_libs\parsers.c:11884)()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
>   (pandas_libs\parsers.c:11755)()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
>   (pandas_libs\parsers.c:28765)()
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
>   7, saw 2

[Followed this stackoverflow thread, but no help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

Comment: `read_table` and other `read_*` functions work on files, not webpages.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid not sure that is true https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table:~:text=Any%20valid%20string%20path%20is%20acceptable.,URLs%2C%20a%20host%20is%20expected.%20A

Answer (score 1):

try this to handle bad lines:

```
k1=pd.read_table(
r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/chipotle.tsv'
,error_bad_lines=False
)
```

Comment: Received following error.

URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777)>

Comment: @prvreddy i assume you are working behind a corporate proxy.... you need to set your proxy before you can access external web resources

Comment: @prvreddy Add "https_proxy" and "http_proxy" to you system environment variable, like: http://proxy.XXXX.com:8020... you can check your OS manual to see how to add environment variables and you IT department for the proxy address. After adding, you need to restart your python to enable the proxy.