# python csv dealing with comma inside column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Dealing with csv file that has text data of novels.

```
book_id, title, content
1, book title 1, All Passion Spent is written in three parts, primarily from the view of an intimate observer. 
2, Book Title 2,  In particular Mr FitzGeorge, a forgotten acquaintance from India who has ever since been in love with her, introduces himself and they form a quiet but playful and understanding friendship. It cost 3,4234 to travel.
```

Text in content column have commas and unfortunately when you try to use pandas.read_csv you get `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error:`

There are some solutions to this problem SO but none of them worked. Tried to read as a regular file and then passed to data frame failed. 
[SO - Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

Comment: Are there ever commas in the `id` or `title`?

Comment: You are getting the error because there is an extra comma in `been in love with her, introduces h`

Comment: Can you replace the first 2 commas with a random delimiters like `@` and change the default delimiter in the csv parser?  `pandas.csv_reaser(filename, sep='@')` and `line.replace(',', '@', maxreplace=2)`. If there is comma in title, you'll need a regex replace to match the title.

Comment: @chrisz there can be separators in the title

Comment: @Rakesh basically index mismatch right more columns than what is in the header.

Comment: As is, with commas in the both title and content, you're not ever going to read it correctly. You'll have to recreate it to use a delimiter other than comma, such as a pipe (|), or have the values quoted to protect the embedded commas.

Comment: That's not a valid `csv` file. Embedded column markers should be escaped so you don't have this problem. So, you'll have to hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading your file and then spliting the content using `str.split(",", 2)` and then convert the result to a DF.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
content = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    header = infile.readline().strip().split(",")
    content = [i.strip().split(",", 2) for i in infile.readlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame(content, columns=header)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  book_id          title                                            content
0       1   book title 1   All Passion Spent is written in three parts, ...
1       2   Book Title 2    In particular Mr FitzGeorge, a forgotten acq...
```

Comment: I like, except you could `content = [i.strip().split(",", 2) for i in infile]` to reduce the memory used by the intermediate `data` list.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks

Comment: @Rakesh this was an example i do have more columns (20) in that case how will split work