# Error when reading csv with merged cells

Tags: python, csv, read.csv

I have a txt file that I open in Excel that has merged cells (see image).

[image].

These cause an error message when reading the file:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 1883, saw 2
```

At the moment I'm manually taking them out in Excel. I'm sure there could be a way to taken these out when reading a file but I can't find anything on SO. I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology though.

Using Excel may also be an option. I just wanted to see if there was a method using Python.

Comment: You cannot merge cells in .csv technically. It is really a text file.

Comment: What you're displaying is not a csv file, it's a capture of some excel screen. CSV is a text file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to skip the headers, you might look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) which suggests the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```