# Python VsCode: cannot find parser.pyx

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error running a python script "cannot find parser.pyx: file not found" and the path is the current working directory + "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx". I cannot find why VsCode is referencing the wkdr instead of the application path which is specified correctly.

Comment: How are you launching the script?

Comment: @BrettCannon Running the Debugger by pressing F5

Comment: The extension always uses the working directory unless you override it in your `launch.json` file.

Comment: @Brett Cannon could you provide a sample? I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @MarkHollas https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_cwd

Comment: Any solution to this? Same problem.

Comment: I experienced the same issue when debugging when I was trying to read a csv-file that doesn't exist. Maybe that helps...

Comment: Use the full path to the file

Answer (score 0):

I shows my solution on the same above problem.
First, I doubted conflict the "parsers.pyx" between "current working directory + pandas_libs\parsers.pyx" made by VScode and pandas library installed.

Solution:
I fixed my .csv file by table editor of PyCharm whicl tell me my problem.

Process:
My code was run on PyCharm. PyCharm telled me a error on csv corruption. such as "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 98 fields in line 230, saw 99" @ [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

So I removed column 99 from my cvs file.

After that, I could read my csv file correctly on VSCode.