# How to skip file if Error tokenizing data error occurs when reading csv file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

When I try to read csv file I get an error `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error`

I have a set of different csv files and see this error occurs across different files

```
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None, sep=',')
        list_.append(df)
        except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
            continue
```

I am trying to see if I can skip reading the entire csv file if this error (`pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error`) occurs while reading a csv file

Answer (score 0):

Request you to try with

```
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Do note that using error_bad_lines=False will cause the offending lines to be skipped
try this ... If it help else i will try to edit and solve it further

Comment: also ... i saw some help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: thanks for the comment, yes I have tried that option as well but it dint help. I am trying to see a way how I could delete these erroneous files

Comment: yes I have tried the suggestions in that link. As I read as I am reading a bunch of files and these errors throw up randomly so I am trying to find a way to skip these erroneous files to overcome this problem..