# Getting error while trying to read csv using pandas Python due to extra column values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the scenario that I am trying to rid of:
I am trying to read the following type of csv:

```
para1,para2,para3,para4
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,5,
1,2,3,4,
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,
```

I am using the following command and getting the following error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df =pd.read_csv("test.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1139, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1995, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 955, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2172, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 5
```

I tried to search for the issue and got this thread on SO:
[Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

So, I tried. This is not what  I was expecting. It is truncating the values.

```
>>> df =pd.read_csv("test.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
b'Skipping line 3: expected 4 fields, saw 5\nSkipping line 5: expected 4 fields, saw 9\n'
>>> df


para1  para2  para3  para4
0      1      2      3      4
1      1      2      3      4
```

What I wanted is something like this:
if there are extra values, then take the columns as the integer values with the highest column found in extra. then make the rest of the values as zero(0) till the last column and read the csv.

The output I am expecting is something like this:

```
>>> df =pd.read_csv("test.csv")
>>> df
   para1  para2  para3  para4    0    1    2    3    4
0      1      2      3      4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      1      2      3      4  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      1      2      3      4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3      2      3      4      5  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  0.0
>>> df = df.fillna(0)
>>> df
   para1  para2  para3  para4    0    1    2    3    4
0      1      2      3      4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1      1      2      3      4  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2      1      2      3      4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3      2      3      4      5  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  0.0
```

But please take a note of, I do not want to take care of the column. Instead the program must automatically understand and make the column headers as given above.

Second, please try to avoid suggesting me to write the header. As there can be number of columns where I might not able to write the header but just leave it as it is. so the missing column header will be the number integer as stated above. Do someone have any solution for the query, please let me know?

Comment: Not efficient solution but would work.. you can read csv file without header first then 2nd time you can read only headers

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar May be but is there no solution with pandas available?

Comment: The above is pandas solution only....maybe you meant to ask if it can be done by tweaking some parameteres in `read_csv` which at least I am not aware of.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Yeah, something that sort of

Comment: I have edited the sample as I forgot to add the extra commas there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code, use `sep='  '`, then an `iloc` which gets first column, then simply `str.split` and `expand=True` which does a new dataframe, and then a `fillna` replacing `NaN`s, and then the final line is to name the columns with a `list` comprehension and a `list(range(...))`.

So you should use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep='  ')
df2 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(',$', '').str.split(',', expand=True).fillna(0)
dd = df.columns[0].split(',')
ff = [str(x) for x in range(len(df2.columns) - len(dd))]
df2.columns = dd + ff
print(df2)
```

Comment: How I can identify whether to add `list(range(5))` or `list(range(10))` or anything? if I have a large dataset I cannot even thing of opening it and count how much to add. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @JafferWilson Edited mine again

Comment: @JafferWilson Happy to help again :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this, but I tested it out and it works using just pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
df= df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
new_header = df.iloc[0].fillna(df.columns.to_series())
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header
```

Comment: assuming `1,"2,2,2",3` are 5 columns and not 3 like with a real CSV parser

Comment: I agree it won't work if your data is structured like that would need a better solution, but it worked for the OP's problem data he posted.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that means that you will have to parse the file until its end to get the actual number of columns, because `pandas.read_csv` has no provision for that requirement.

If high performance is not a concern (*), a simple way is to rely on the good old csv module and dynamically add columns as needed:

```
with open('test.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    header = next(rd)     # initialize column names from first row
    next_key = 0          # additional columns will start at '0'
    data = {k: list() for k in header}  # initialize data list per column
    for row in rd:
        while len(row) > len(header):    # add eventual new columns
            header.append(str(next_key))
            data[header[-1]] = [np.nan] * len(data[header[0]])
            next_key += 1                # increase next column name
        # eventually extend the row up to the header size
        row.extend([np.nan] * (len(header) - len(row)))
        # and add data to the column lists
        for i, k in enumerate(header): data[k].append(row[i])

# data is now in a dict format, suitable to feed DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

(*) above code will not be very efficient because it adds element to lists one at a time. This would be terrible for pandas DataFrame, and is not very very nice even for Python lists. It could be improved by allocating bunches in `numpy.ndarray` but at the price of increased complexity.

Comment: May be this will help. But what you mean by `If performance is not a concern (*)`? Obviously, performance is a considered concern.

Comment: @JafferWilson: What I mean is that this code does not pretend to be as efficient as the C parser of `read_csv`. On a fairly recent computer, it should be able to process csv files up to several Mbytes. If you intend to process many files of several Gbytes, it would deserve low level optimization.

Comment: @JafferWilson: ...Said differently, my advice is that you should give it a try, and only if performance is not acceptable then try to use pre_allocation to speedup things.

Comment: Sure I will give it a try