# Find the extra column values and move into different columns - Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a `.csv` file into a `pandas` dataframe and have the output like this;

```
Name                DOB         Phone           Address           Unnamed: 4      Unnammed: 5     
WERNER,BRADLEY D    11/14/1962  563-921-9775    518 E 1st St N
THOMPSON,LARRY E    1/22/1950   235-660-0613    516 Clark St Box 
CORNELIO,LESA L     11/11/1977                                    479-308-3957    208 S Sorenson Ave 
SCHUBERT,BONITA J   6/29/1966   756-364-8059    120 S RICE ST
```

From above, I want to find the values that are present in `Unnamed:<number>` columns as move two columns to the left (into `Phone` and `Address` columns).

I tried this,

```
for i in df.columns:
    if i.startswith("Unnamed"):
        column_val = df[i].dropna()
        print(column_val)
```

Here I get the output,

```
> 479-308-3957
  Name: Unnamed: 4, dtype: object 

> 208 S Sorenson Ave
  Name: Unnamed: 5, dtype: object
```

Now, I get the values needed, but now, I want to move it two columns to the left. Output would be,

```
 Name               DOB         Phone           Address               
 WERNER,BRADLEY D   11/14/1962  563-921-9775    518 E 1st St N
 THOMPSON,LARRY E   1/22/1950   235-660-0613    516 Clark St Box 
 CORNELIO,LESA L     11/11/1977 479-308-3957    208 S Sorenson Ave 
 SCHUBERT,BONITA J  6/29/1966   756-364-8059    120 S RICE ST
```

Also, if I have a big data frame with multiple values under `Unnamed` columns will my method to find out the values be efficient?

Any help would be great and an efficient way will be much awesome.

Comment: You'd be better off fixing the code that reads your data.

Comment: @cs95 That is what I found online when I was searching for reading corrupted data from `.csv` (i.e. `pd.read_csv(..., error_bad_lines = False)`). I found a way around based on (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251624/6626093) answer and read in a file, save back as `.CSV` and read saved file into pandas. The reason is I don't want to lose data and I want to automate this. Hope this helps to explain my situation.