# KeyError: "[] not found in axis" while dropping row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to drop a single row in a csv-file using pandas lib for python. The row that should be dropped contains a specific id. While executing the script, I always get a KeyError: "['12345'] not found in axis". Does anybody have a solution?

Example dataframe:

```
id     date   time
12345  11-7   11am
12346  11-7   12pm
12347  11-7   1pm
```

The code:

```py
import pandas as pd
id = "123456"
filename = datacollection.csv
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8", index_col="id")
data.drop(id, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Expected result would be:

```
id     date   time
12346  11-7   12pm
12347  11-7   1pm
```

Easy as that. However, I tried a lot of different solutions provided on various sites on the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: `'123456'` is *not* in your `id` column - you have a typo. I think you meant `id = "12345"`

Comment: Eagle-eye Dan!   Nice!

Comment: Another common problem are dtypes.  Sometimes your index is integer 123456 and you are using string '123456'.

Comment: Thanks Dan, you're right. I edited the post.

Comment: Scott, when I convert id to an integer it runs through, however, the row has not been deleted from the csv file..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, `id = "123456"` doesn't exist in your data. So, please, verify it first.

Try this:

Data: `Dataset.csv`

```
id date time
12345 11-7 11am
12346 11-7 12pm
12347 11-7 1pm
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
id = 12345
filename = 'Dataset.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=' ', encoding="utf-8", index_col=['id'])
data = data.drop(data.loc[data.index==id].index)
print(data)
```

output:

```
       date  time
id               
12346  11-7  12pm
12347  11-7   1pm
```

Comment: When I remove index_col="id" from the above code it runs through (otherwise I get a Keyerror 'id'), but then I get the following warning and the row has not been deleted: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)

Comment: Anubhav, thank you very much. Unfortunately, I get the error: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 16, saw 12

Comment: @rapha, this is a different problem. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: hmm.. I read the other article and tried the solutions, but in the end, it does not work. The line is not dropped...

Comment: Yes, definitely. But your code works, I simply forgot to save the file. I think I should stop coding for today. Anyway, thank you very very much. If you have the time: Would you maybe explain the snippet "data.loc[data.index==id].index" a little bit?

Comment: Yeah sure, `data.loc[data.index==id].index` basically returns the index value of row in case the inner condition, i.e., `data.index==given_id` satisfies. Then, the output index is passed into `data.drop()' which finally drops the row with given index. In case, condition doesn't satisfies no index is passes, hence nothing dropped.