# Problems to read german csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having a german csv file, which I want to read with `pd.read_csv`.

**Data:**

The original file looks like this:

[image]

So it has two Columns (A,B) and the seperator should be `';'`,

**Problem:**
When I ran the command:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../GermanNews/articles.csv',
                      encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep=';')
```

I get the error:
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3`

**Half-Solution:**
I understand this could have several reasons, but when I ran the command:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../GermanNews/articles.csv',
                      encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep='delimiter')
```

I get the following dataset back:

```
    0
0   Etat;Die ARD-Tochter Degeto hat sich verpflich...
1   Etat;App sei nicht so angenommen worden wie ge...
2   Etat;'Zum Welttag der Suizidprävention ist es ...
3   Etat;Mitarbeiter überreichten Eigentümervertre...
4   Etat;Service: Jobwechsel in der Kommunikations...
```

so I only get one column instead of the two desired columns,

**Target:**
any idea how to load the dataset correctly that I have:

```
    0       1
0   Etat    Die ARD-Tochter Degeto hat sich verpflich...
1   Etat    App sei nicht so angenommen worden wie ge...
```

**Hints/Tries:**

When I run the search function over my data in excel, I am also not finding any `;`in it.

It seems like that some lines have more then two columns (as you can see for example in line 3 and 13 of my example

Comment: Is there a ; in one of your sentences that is misinterpreted as a delimiter?

Comment: I searched in excel over the dataset, there is no other ; in my dataset

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe the following link already provides an answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: It appears in your Excel screenshot that the third line has been split into three columns, so it is also finding something it thinks is a delimiter there. Can you share the full text of the first three lines?

Comment: Simon you are right, somehow I have sometimes 2 columns and osmetimes three, in line 13 I also have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is create one column `DataFrame` with separator not in data like `delimiter` and then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n` parameter and `expand=True` for new `DataFrame`:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../GermanNews/articles.csv',
                       encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep='delimiter')

#more general solution is use some value NOT exist in data like yen ¥
#dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../GermanNews/articles.csv',
#                      encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep='¥')

df = dataset[0].str.split(';', n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['A','B']
print (df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Skim through your texts carefully. If you find no leads, follow the below solution.

---

**Note:** This is not a perfect solution but a hack and has worked for me multiple times when I worked with German text since I found no other solution.

I just read the whole thing as such and split the string into two desired columns by splitting on the first occurrence of a delimiter.

```
df['col1'] = df[0].str.split(';', 1).str[0]
df['col2'] = df[0].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
```

Output:

```
                            0    col1                   col2
0        Etat;Die ARD-Tochter..  Etat        Die ARD-Tochter
1         Etat;App sei nicht...  Etat          App sei nicht 
2  Etat;Mitarbeiter überreich..  Etat  Mitarbeiter überreich
```

I just trimmed the texts to demonstrate the example.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('german.txt', sep=';', header = None, encoding='iso-8859-1')
df
```

Output:

```
       0    1
0   Etat    Die ARD-Tochter Degeto hat sich verpflich...
1   Etat    App sei nicht so angenommen worden wie ge...
2   Etat    'Zum Welttag der Suizidprävention ist es ...
3   Etat    Mitarbeiter überreichten Eigentümervertre...
4   Etat    Service: Jobwechsel in der Kommunikations...
```

Comment: sorry, this does not work, as I have somewhere 3 columns in my original dataframe and not only 2