# ParserError with value containing delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
"ID"|"Description"|"Date"
"1234"|"good text"|"2019-10-12"
"9012"|"bad"text|here""|"2018-01-12"
```

I am trying to write to a new CSV that looks like this:

```
+--------+------------------+--------------+
|  "ID"  |  "Description"   |    "Date"    |
+--------+------------------+--------------+
| "1234" | "good text"      | "2019-10-12" |
| "9012" | "bad text|here"  | "2018-01-12" |
+--------+------------------+--------------+
```

The issue is that the delimiter "|" is contained in one of the description values, namely "bad|text". So when I run something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-16', sep='|')
```

I see:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

The only resolution I see is to skip the rows containing the delimiter but obviously I want them:

[Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

Any suggestions?

Note that file is encoded as UTF-16.

Comment: Because that sample is properly quoted, there shouldn't be an issue reading it in.

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem, it is read in correctly. You can try to add `quotechar='"'` in your `pd.read_csv` line

Comment: @Erfan Updated example. You should be able to reproduce now. Thanks!

Comment: An option is to parse your csv and replace the separator.  Replace `"|"` with `","`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution, the key `engine='python-fwf'`, regex seperator and some cleaning.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('file_in.csv', engine='python-fwf', sep='"|"', quotechar='"')
df.to_csv('file_out.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

Output:

```
print(df)
     ID Description                 Date
0  1234   good text           2019-10-12
1  9012   bad" text  here ""|"2018-01-12
```

file_out.csv:

```
ID|Description|Date
1234|good text|2019-10-12
9012|"bad"" text"|"here """"|""2018-01-12"
```

Comment: This one resulted in: pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 7 fields in line 3, saw 9. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: @kjmerf sorry my bad, I had slightly different csv. Check `engine='python-fwf'`. Result is closer but not exact yet.

Comment: Still not exactly right... Run df.columns and you see you only have ID in one column and the other is Description|Date

Comment: I got: `Index(['ID', 'Description', 'Date'], dtype='object')`  Do you use `sep='"|"'`?

Comment: Yes but remember the file is UTF-16. If you are testing, save a file as UTF 16 and then try...

Comment: Quick idea, if `Description` and `Date` are merged into one string column, you can get `Date` by stripping last 10 characters into separate column. Not clean solution but entry data is also not clean ;)