# Python Pandas read error, What does this error mean?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to import a `csv` file from the [mental health website](https://statswales.gov.wales/Catalogue/Health-and-Social-Care/Mental-Health/Psychiatric-Census/patientsinmentalhealthhospitalsandunitsinwaleswithamentalillness).

I imported the correct libraries and directory for the file is correct.

I used this line:

```
export = pd.read_csv('export.csv')
```

here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0d82cf77b73c> in <module>
----> 1 export = pd.read_csv('export.csv')
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, 
header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, 
true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, 
na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, 
dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, 
quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, 
warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         ) 
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    461 
    462     try:
--> 463         data = parser.read(nrows)
    464     finally:
    465         parser.close()
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1152     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1153         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
 -> 1154         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1155 
   1156         # May alter columns / col_dict
 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2057     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2058         try:
-> 2059             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2060         except StopIteration:
   2061             if self._first_chunk:
 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows() 
 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
 pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
 ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 13
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Answer (score 1):

The error actually means that the 8th line in the file was expecting 1 field but found 13.

I think the error came because when you tried to export the file from the website, you also checked 'Include Title' and 'Include Metadata' buttons. Don't check these buttons and just select 'Comma separated' in Export Type. It should work.

Comment: Ah, amazing, un selecting the metadata and title seemed to do the trick. Thank you so much.