# How to fix ParseError while reading csv data with read_csv method?

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

Data downloaded from: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

In order to ensure the code is reproducible, I am trying to do the following but it gives me a parsing error.

```
train = pd.read_csv("https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/GQf0y8ebHO0C4JXscPPp%2Fversions%2FXkNkvXwqPPVG0Qt3MtQT%2Ffiles%2Ftrain.csv")
```

**getting this error**

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

Here are the first 3 lines of the file:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
```

I think it is because the `"Name"` column has commas separating the first and last name
I tired adding **"** as a separator in the `pd.read_csv` but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?
thank you

Comment: The first line of code should suffice; `train` will already be a pandas data frame. I'm slightly confused as to what you are trying to achieve with the second line of code.

Comment: I took out the second line of code. When I run the code l have, it gives the error I listed.

Comment: I'll refer you to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data). The summary is that you can skip "bad" lines by doing `train = pd.read_csv("https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/GQf0y8ebHO0C4JXscPPp%2Fversions%2FXkNkvXwqPPVG0Qt3MtQT%2Ffiles%2Ftrain.csv", error_bad_lines=False)`. I'd recommend that you examine the file and see which lines are causing problems.

Comment: Jake Tae, I used the bad lines method and upon analyzing the lines it skips, there doesn't seem to be any problems with them. If I download the file directly to my computer and then read it in, there are no parsing errors. This is a kaggle contest so the data is clean. Do you have any other suggestions?