# read_csv fails for some CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to Python.
I tried with this code

```
import pandas
asto = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Acer\Documents\crawling_commuterline.csv")
```

Then, I got the error like this

```
C:\Users\Acer\Documents\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Acer/Documents/tokenisasi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/Documents/tokenisasi.py", line 2, in <module>
    asto = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Acer\Documents\crawling_commuterline.csv")
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 458, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1196, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2155, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 918, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2042, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 4


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please give me advice about the wrong of that code. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the full text of the error message (including the traceback) into your question _as text_ - I for one won't read text in images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the delimiter and assign header later also it best practice to import pandas as of and import numpy as np before that:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep='delimiter', header=None)
df.columns = ['COL_List']
```