# Stuck with an Error while importing data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, compiler-errors, importerror

So this is what error looks like when I try to run the pd.read_csv function and I am totally stuck . And I also checked that I am in the same directory where the data is so ya thats it

Help if know what's happening here :

PS : the data file size is 14MB

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2a5563273d31> in <module>
----> 1 data=pd.read_csv('ufo_data.csv',header=None)
      2 data.head()
      3 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    456 
    457     try:
--> 458         data = parser.read(nrows)
    459     finally:
    460         parser.close()

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1194     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1195         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1196         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1197 
   1198         # May alter columns / col_dict

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2153     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2154         try:
-> 2155             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2156         except StopIteration:
   2157             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 877, saw 12
```

Comment: Show us the line 877.

Comment: looks like one row of your data had an extra comma/element

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Answer (score 1):

Just added a separator like this and it got fixed :

data=pd.read_csv("File_path", sep='\t')

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

this will cause the offending lines to be skipped

Comment: Thanks for answering but it did not work rather I found the answer