# how to use pandas to remove the no needed datas?

Tags: python, pandas

Data:
[the tsv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjfjB.png)

This is what the Tsv data looks like, how do I use pandas to remove all the information but the words and the tags? for example only keeps :
[Keep the part I circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKiAs.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not respect the rules of StackOverflow. Please take a while to read:

- [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

But the answer is (probably):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.tsv', comment='#', header=None, sep='\t')
```

Comment: @Lee. Is it what you expect?