# IndexError and ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying read and open a csv file in python using `customer_data = pd.read_csv('file')`. But getting error like `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 2`. how to fix this error.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)