# Disable Upload in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, parsing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i have a problem with my jupyter notebook.
I wanna add a csv-file to my project but i get following error:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jens/Projektarbeit - Ticket Intelligence/train_mail.csv")
```

```
    ParserError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-1e20204919e4> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jens/Projektarbeit - Ticket Intelligence/train_mail.csv")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    456 
    457     try:
--> 458         data = parser.read(nrows)
    459     finally:
    460         parser.close()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1194     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1195         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1196         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1197 
   1198         # May alter columns / col_dict

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2153     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2154         try:
-> 2155             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2156         except StopIteration:
   2157             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 16, saw 6
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may be due to a faulty input line in the file. Use the following to drop the lines of this sort.

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Jens/Projektarbeit - Ticket Intelligence/train_mail.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn´t work

Comment: @Jens - What is the error now?

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: I guess the encoding of the file is different. Try adding `encoding='utf-16'` in pd.read_csv

Comment: No, it hasn´t changed