# panda unable to read the csv file ? showing this error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
TF_MODEL_URL = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1/1'
mo = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1/1')
IMAGE_SHAPE = (321,321)
df= pd.read_csv(LABLE_MAP_URL)
```

the error is

```
if self.low_memory:
--> 230         chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
    231         # destructive to chunks
    232         data = _concatenate_chunks(chunks)

   1775         index,
   1776         columns,
   1777         col_dict,
-> 1778     ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
   1779         nrows
   1780     )
       deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: actually i tried to import the tensorflow hub landmark link https://tfhub.dev/google/on_device_vision/classifier/landmarks_classifier_asia_V1/1

Comment: please include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors... everything including the `Traceback: (most recent call last)` to the `XXXError: message`.

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is from pandas IO tools, so the error likely occured when you are reading the .csv. As you didn't show the file and this is not a reproducible example, you should check the file and see what went wrong. You also didn't show the entire traceback so it is difficult to tell what kind of error it is, but I would suggest this part of the traceback you provided seems somewhat similar to the part of [panda's official documentation on malformed lines with too many fields](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html?highlight=reading#handling-bad-lines).

**Edit:**

As suspected, the error you showed does appear to be bad lines caused by the dataset, so this may be a possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data). Have you tried

```
data = pd.read_csv(LABLE_MAP_URL, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

as the answer in the dupe suggested?

Comment: Thanks for your time and here is the full error pics https://at.tumblr.com/wyet/699283922073288704/wvvx06m4rrfv