# Can't open some .csv file using read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am writing a Python function to open two .csv files and make changes to the data inside. I am using pandas and pd.read_csv('text') to open the files. Everything works well and the function works for one .csv file. However, when I try it on a different smaller .csv file the file cannot even open.

This is part of the error I am getting when I try to open the .csv file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Downloads\test\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 950, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 611, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1778, in read
    ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 230, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 808, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 866, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 852, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1973, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 8836, saw 5
```

This is the code I am using to access the .csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

All the files are in the correct folders and the file paths are all correct. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: don't post *part* of the error. Post the **full error message including the stack trace**

Comment: The last thing in the traceback is the error message. We need that part too.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited it

Comment: Your `CSV` file is malformed: `Expected 4 fields in line 8836, saw 5`.

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: That failing line would be interesting to look at. Perhaps whatever wrote this CSV didn't escape an internal comma correctly.