# Adding multiple text files into a Pandas dataframe ParserError

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This topic has been covered many times here but none of the solutions have worked for me. I am trying to add all text files from a folder into a dataframe. The code below is working IF I only have 1 file in the folder but as soon as I add another, I get the error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 40, saw 2.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
import glob

#define path to dir containing the summary text files
files_folder = "/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports/"
files = []

#create a df list using list comprehension
files = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_folder,"*txt"))] 

#concatanate the list of df's into one df
files_df = pd.concat(files)


print(files_df)
```

I have also tried this approach with the same result:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = '/data/TB/WA_dirty_prep_reports'
summary_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

df_list = []

df_list = (pd.read_csv(file) for file in summary_files)

big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Re: the link you shared. Another issue I am having is that I have tried adding sep='\t' parameter but get an error there as well. These text files actually contain multiple tables, is it possible that is a problem? It seems I would get an error with only one file in that case too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, with 3 dummy `.txt` files. It looks like some lines **inside** the txt files do not get parsed as other lines, maybe because of a separator issue. Try this:

```py
files = [pd.read_csv(file, on_bad_lines='skip') for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(files_folder,"*txt"))]
```

as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18039057/12846804).

Of course that might not be satisfactory to you because you will be missing lines.

It does NOT look like the issue is about having either one, or two, or more txt files. You probably get the same issue with your second file alone.

---

Now you are mentioning **multiple tables inside one file**. Nice try but read the docs again. `pd.read_csv` expects **one** table.
Of course a second table will likely have a different number of columns, resulting in `ParseError`. Tweaking the separator won't change that. ***Line 40* in your text file is probably the transition between two tables.**
In this case, rather look in the direction of stackoverflow.com/q/34184841/12846804. It doesn't look like there's an easy way, but that was from 7 years ago.

Comment: thank you, on_bad_lines= 'skip' parameter seems to be working.  i was also able to add the parameter sep='\t' and it prints without error but there is a lot of NaN. I think these files are problematic because they contain multiple tables