# Python pandas reading csv ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, error-handling, read-csv

Difficulty reading a .csv file and I get this error:

```
ParserError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-39a4e05f4c14> in <cell line: 1>() 
----> 1 krediler_df = pd.read_csv('KREDILER.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-9', thousands=',', decimal='.') 
      2 ibra_tahsilat_df = pd.read_csv('IBRA_TAHSILAT.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-9', thousands=',', decimal='.') 
      3 
      4 
      5 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error() 
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 5
```

Should I change anything on that file like should I convert it to .xlsx, and which columns and rows are problematic?

Answer (score 0):

**What causes the issue**

At **line 3** of of *KREDILER.csv*, `pd.read_csv` finds 5 cells instead of the expected 3 (previous rows). It might have to do with the delimiters it was asked to look for? some special character?

**One thing you may try**

Add argument `on_bad_lines='skip'`, as in [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18039057/12846804):

```
pd.read_csv('KREDILER.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-9', 
            thousands=',', decimal='.', 
            on_bad_lines='skip')
```

However, keep in mind that it won't solve your problem, only skip the lines that are found not to fit.

**For further help**

Consider printing a portion of the file, as text, in the body of your question, so we may see what's wrong with line 3.

Comment: Honestly I could not understand what you mean I am kinda confused . The output should be 5668 rows × 3 columns

Comment: @HelloWorld I have improved answer readability. You'll need to print some of the file in the question for further help.