# Error reading CSV file in Python - "PandasParserError"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Introduction:** I'm encountering an issue while trying to read data from a CSV file in Python using the Pandas library.

**Description:** I'm working with Python 3.8 and Pandas 1.3.1. The problem occurs when I attempt to read the CSV file using the **`pd.read_csv`** function. The code snippet is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Attempt to read the CSV file

file_path = 'path/to/my/file.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

**Error Messages:** I'm getting the following error message:

```
PandasParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4
```

Expected vs. Actual Behavior:
I expected the code to read the CSV file successfully, but it throws the "PandasParserError" with the mentioned message.

Research Efforts:
I've already checked the Pandas documentation and tried specifying different delimiters using the delimiter parameter in pd.read_csv. However, the issue persists.

Environment:
I'm using VSCode as my IDE on Windows 10.

Comment: What does your csv file look like? Can you show the first five lines (something like `head -n 5 /path/to/file.csv`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/pandas-parser-cparsererror-error-tokenizing-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

This will skip bad lines in the csv

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about this but the simplest thing may just be examining and fixing the CSV, the error indicates that the 4th line of your CSV has an extra field.

If you don't want to / can't examine the CSV pandas has some options for getting around the error:

1. Skip bad lines, as pointed out by @gtomer, this will successfully read in your file but you will lose the rows giving errors. Depending on your dataset losing rows may not be an acceptable option.

`data = pd.read_csv(file_path, on_bad_lines='skip')`

2. use cols, using this option will keep all rows but only the data from selected columns. You can select columns by name or index.

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])`

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=[0,1,2])`